# What are some of the optimization compilers perform on read that requires the use of Volatile keyword?

Tags: c++, volatile

Thinking in C++ says

> the qualifier volatile tells the
>   compiler “You never know when this
>   will change,” and prevents the
>   compiler from performing any
>   optimizations based on the stability
>   of that variable.

What are some of the optimization (besides caching) that the compiler performs?

Comment: Are you asking specifically about optimizations that are prevented by the use of the `volatile` qualification?

Answer (score 9):

The most basic optimization there is: storing the value of the variable in a CPU register.  Declaring it volatile forces the code generator to always reload the value from memory instead of using the cached copy in the register.

Answer (score 3):

A common optimization is reordering of read or write operations.  This can help achieve better parallelism for pipelined operations which may have otherwise resulted in "stalls" (where the compiler injects waits or no-ops to prevent [hazards](http://www.cs.iastate.edu/~prabhu/Tutorial/PIPELINE/hazards.html)).

If a variable is marked volatile, it can prevent this kind of operation reordering through the use of memory barriers.  How it does so is implementation dependent.  To see what Microsoft C++ compiler does, you can refer to the [MSDN reference on `volatile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a04hfd%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).